# Any good ways of combining only necessary css and js for web app

Tags: javascript, css, version-control, minify

I have been improving the structure of a web app's frontend and have done things like combine and minify css/js files, version files, and building out some templates. However I was looking at some web tools and it is saying there is a ton of unused js/css. Are there any suggestions on 
 -discovering the completely necessary code
 -combining, minifying, and versioning the right code for the page
I am mainly looking for like a logical suggestion any code samples would be great. I am specifically using python, cheetah templates, yui-compressor, modified time for versioning, mod_rewrite and gzip on apache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) Firefox extension for streamlining CSS:

> Dust-Me Selectors is a Firefox
>   extension (for v1.5 or later) that
>   finds unused CSS selectors.
>
> It extracts all the selectors from all
>   the stylesheets on the page you're
>   viewing, then analyzes that page to
>   see which of those selectors are not
>   used. The data is then stored so that
>   when testing subsequent pages,
>   selectors can be crossed off the list
>   as they're encountered.
>
> You can test pages individually, or
>   spider an entire site, and you'll end
>   up with a profile of which selectors
>   are not used anywhere.

For JavaScript, take a look at the [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) which can calculate codependencies within your code and remove redundancies.

> The Closure Compiler is a tool for
>   making JavaScript download and run
>   faster. It is a true compiler for
>   JavaScript. Instead of compiling from
>   a source language to machine code, it
>   compiles from JavaScript to better
>   JavaScript. It parses your JavaScript,
>   analyzes it, removes dead code and
>   rewrites and minimizes what's left. It
>   also checks syntax, variable
>   references, and types, and warns about
>   common JavaScript pitfalls.

Comment: Is there something like Dust-Me for javascript that would be really useful I am the first front-end person to work on this app and I am sure there is tons of unused JS but unsure of how to find it

Comment: I think the Google Closure Compiler - http://goo.gl/8UBO - will try to calculate dependencies within your JavaScript and and remove redundant code